# How to convert promise into callback in node js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, callback, promise, firebase-authentication

Here is simple scenario..

I want to convert these code given in firebase documentation to my api..

How can I convert it to callback function?

```
var uid = "some-uid";

admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
  .then(function(customToken) {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
  });
```

Here is the link of documentation..

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
```

Comment: Don't! Embrace promises!

Comment: What promise library are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use node-style callbacks on a promise, invoke them like this:

```
.then(function(result) {
    callback(null, result);
}, function(error) {
    callback(error);
});
```

Some promise libraries also have helper functions for that, like Bluebirds [`.asCallback(callback)`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html).

Comment: If the callback throws in the success function you'd have an unhandled rejection - which is not what you'd expect - you need to try/catch the error and to `throw` it outside of promised context if the callback threw.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Actually I'd *expect* an unhandled rejection if the callback throws (which it never should), but yeah we could add `.catch(process.emit.bind(process, "uncaughtException"))` after the `then`

Answer (score 8):

In NodeJS > 8.2 you have a [`require('util').callbackify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_callbackify_original) (opposite of [`require('util').promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)):

```
const { callbackify } = require('util');

callbackify(() => admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid))((err, customToken) => {
  // ...
});
```

Or if you have a callback from somewhere else:

```
const { callbackify } = require('util');

callbackify(() => promise)(callback);
```

Note that it receives a *function that returns a promise* and not the promise itself, and it returns a *function that receives a callback* and does not receive a callback itself.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
function(uid, cb){
  admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
  .then(function(customToken) {
    cb(null, customToken);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
      cb(error, null);
  });
}
```

where cb is like `function callback(error, token){...}`

Comment: Don't do that. If `cb` throws, it will be called again.

Comment: @Bergi with it's own error and this shouldn't create any sort of recursion but your solution is cleaner.

Comment: No, not recursion, but still it is problematic for callbacks that are expected to be called only once.

Comment: @Bergi  Yes absolutely. I have upvoted your answer. It should be the accepted one